# What is the second phase of photosynthesis?

Tags: cell-biology, photosynthesis

I really want to know what the second phase of photosynthesis (in the dark) is. I have a fair understanding of the first cycle where molecular oxygen is generated under the influence of light, but I don't understand the second cycle which can take place in the dark. It would greatly help to have a graphic of the second phase of photosynthesis.

Note: it is not for my homework, but for my own understanding. My textbook doesn't explain things very well.

Comment: I believe you are going to have to either elaborate on your question greatly and put forth some effort in specifics of what you are asking

Comment: photosynthesis has 2 phases.the first one is made in light,were oxygen is produced(i know this phase cause is easier and my teacher has it very good explained).The second phase is made in dark,were dioxide carbon is produced,but i don't know why and how.that's why i asked...

Comment: There are more than enough resources you can seek online to find the answer. Google the calvin cycle

Comment: actually i have,and i have found a lot of answers.but i posted here too,because i wanted even more answers. but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I've voted to close because it seems like a homework question. What specifically is unclear to you about the second phase? Why does it confuse you more than the other phases?

Comment: well it is not for my homework,but it is for my school.I didn't know the calvin cycle,cause my book is a sh** book and doesn't explain it very well.and that's why i asked...

Comment: @user16901 What exactly do you want to know about Calvin cycle. Even after the edit the question is a little broad?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an overview of both the Light and Dark cycles of photosynthesis, which looked particularly useful to me as it shows that the energy-carriers ATP and NADPH<sub>2</sub> generated through solar energy are used in the dark cycle to generate sugars.

[image: PhotoSynthesis].

Here is another one that shows more details on the precursors involved in the Calvin cycle:

[image: CalvinCycle]

As commented by others, googling 'dark cycle' or its synonyms will give thousands of optional images to choose from if these don't suffice. The first one is taken from tutorvista.com the second one from users.rcn.com.

Comment: The dark reactions don't necessarily need to be in the dark; they're called that because they don't require light.

Comment: yes you are right